# How to remove products from compare collection in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, compare

**Looking for a better way to add and remove the product on click of same icon.**

If a product is already added to the compare collection then on next click of that icon, It should  remove the product from compare collection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
protected  $_productloader;
protected $_compareItemFactory;
protected $_catalogProductCompareList;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Compare\ItemFactory $compareItemFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Compare\ListCompare $catalogProductCompareList,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productloader
) {
    $this->_productloader = $productloader;
    $this->_compareItemFactory = $compareItemFactory;
    $this->_catalogProductCompareList = $catalogProductCompareList;
}

public function execute()
{
    $productId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('product');
    $product=$this->_productloader->create()->load($productId);
    $compareitem=$this->_compareItemFactory->create()->loadByProduct($product);
    if($compareitem):
    $this->_catalogProductCompareList->removeProduct($product);
    else:
    $this->_catalogProductCompareList->addProduct($product);
    endif;
}
```

Comment: For this need to create new file or change in existing.please show path.

Comment: @KetanKpBorada create new is good but you can modify the existing as your requirement.

Comment: please show full path with file name.

Comment: @KetanKpBorada kindly add your module ad redirect it on your controllers don't try to edit the core file.

Comment: @QaisarSatti Where is PSR-2? (You're 22k user)

Comment: @ToanNguyen it was write code for test but thanks for notice and 22k not mean i am best.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove product from compare collection using below code:

```
<a href="#" class="action tocompare" title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Remove Compare')); ?>"
           aria-label="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Remove Compare')); ?>"
         data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $compareHelper->getPostDataRemove($_product); ?>'
                role="button">
      <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Remove Compare') ?></span>
 </a>
```

Comment: where is added this code please specify on file and path

Answer (score 0):

This work for me,

```
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session\Proxy              $sessionProxy,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Compare\ListCompare $listCompare,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Compare\ItemFactory $compareItemFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\CustomerData\CompareProducts      $compareProducts,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory              $productloader
    ) {
        $this->_productloader = $productloader;
        $this->_compareItemFactory = $compareItemFactory;
        $this->compareProducts = $compareProducts;
        $this->sessionProxy = $sessionProxy;
        $this->listCompare = $listCompare;
    }

   public function getCompareList()
    {
        return $this->compareProducts->getSectionData();
    }

    public function removePrd(){
    $listt = $this->getCompareList();
        foreach ($listt['items'] as $key => $comparelist) {

            $prdName = $comparelist['name'];
            $prdidd = $comparelist['id'];

            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($prdidd);
            $product = $this->_productloader->create()->load($prdidd);
            $compareitem = $this->_compareItemFactory->create()->loadByProduct($product);

            if (!empty($compareitem)):
                $compareitem->delete($product);
            endif;
        }
```

Thank you.